# Spring property Injection using annotations

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations

I want to configure below type of bean initialization to be performed by annotation.

Below is sample bean configuration in xml type and want to configure this kind of bean using annotations.

```
<bean id="Animal" class="aaa.type.Animal">
    <property name="Animal" value="${Animal}" />
    <property name="AnimalFamily" >
        <bean class="aaa.type.AnimalFamily">
            <property name="AnimalCharactertitic">
                <list>
                    <bean class="aaa.type.AnimalColor">
                        <property name="name" value="Color" />
                        <property name="value" value="${color}" />
                    </bean>
                    <bean class="aaa.type.AnimalType">
                        <property name="name" value="Animal Type" />
                        <property name="value" value="${AnimalType}" />
                    </bean>                     
                </list>
            </property>     
        </bean>
</property>
</bean>
```

Comment: What is the issue you have faced?

Comment: Pls share the configuration class you have written for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfigurationClass {
    @Bean
    public AnimalCharactertitic animalColor(@Value("${color}") String color) {
        AnimalCharactertitic animalCharactertitic = new AnimalCharactertitic();
        animalCharactertitic.setName("Color");
        animalCharactertitic.setValue(color);
        return animalCharactertitic;
    }

    @Bean
    public AnimalCharactertitic animalType(@Value("${AnimalType}") String animalType) {
        AnimalCharactertitic animalCharactertitic = new AnimalCharactertitic();
        animalCharactertitic.setName("Animal Type");
        animalCharactertitic.setValue(animalType);
        return animalCharactertitic;
    }

    @Bean
    public AnimalFamily animalFamily(@Autowired AnimalCharactertitic animalColor,
         @Autowired AnimalCharactertitic animalType) {

        AnimalFamily animalFamily = new AnimalFamily();

        List<AnimalCharactertitic> animalCharactertitics = new ArrayList<>();
        animalCharactertitics.add(animalColor);
        animalCharactertitics.add(animalType);

        animalFamily.setAnimalCharactertitic(animalCharactertitics);

        return animalFamily;
    }

    @Bean
    public Animal animal(@Value("${Animal}") String animal, @Autowired AnimalFamily animalFamily) {

        Animal animal = new Animal();
        animal.setAnimal(animal);
        animal.setAnimalFamily(animalFamily);

        return animal;
    }
}
```